# Enable Bluetooth Adapter for BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagle-bone

I recently bought a [USB 2.0 Bluetooth Adapter](http://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le). It claims to have support from Linux kernels of versions 3.4 and higher. I have a **BeagleBone Black** with **Debian GNU/Linux 7** image and kernel 3.8. I am developing on BeagleBone Black by hosting it through USB with `ssh`.

I have tried both hot plugging and  plugging in before boot and failed.

Then, I tried [this tutorial](http://michaelhleonard.com/enable-bluetooth-on-beaglebone-black/). However, I cannot find the `connman` directory on my BeagleBone Black device. I looked up and assumed I needed to install the `connman` package, but my BeagleBone Black has no internet access.

I have also tried `lsusb -v`, as suggested by an answer of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754699/usb-bluetooth-dongle-isnt-recognized-by-beaglebone-black) to this, with no luck. The weird thing is, while `lsusb` itself prints

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

`lsusb -v` only prints

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

then hangs. Information regarding bus 002, which I believe the device is connected to, is not printed. I have to restart the `ssh` connection to get back to work.

How should I approach to get the dongle to work on my BeagleBone Black? If the `connman` package is sufficient, how do I install it on my BeagleBone Black without internet access. Why does `lsusb -v` hang?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem turned out to be that my BeagleBone Black is flawed/damaged. I plugged the Bluetooth Adapter into a plain new BeagleBone Black before powering it, and the Bluetooth Adapter is recognized! Not only does `lsusb` prints out the adapter info, but also `lsusb -v` does not hang at all. The overall performance of the new board (boot time, compilation time, execution time) is also several times better. I suspect that it was due to the various improper power-off.

In case anyone is just as careless, the BeagleBone Black **SHALL** be powered off by:

- Holding down the power button for about 8 seconds then releasing it.
- Using `halt` or `shutdown -h now` command in the Userspace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this tutorial, you will need internet to download some packages. http://www.instructables.com/id/Wireless-Arduino-Control-Using-the-BeagleBone-Blac/step2/Configuring-the-BBB-or-RPi-for-Bluetooth-Operation/

Comment: The thing is that my Bluetooth adapter is not even enabled/recognized. As mentioned, `lsusb` prints the above output. Not to mention I do not have internet access on my BeagleBone Black.